# (Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "snap-store") stuck

Tags: command-line, software-installation, sudo, 20.10, snap-store

I am new to Ubuntu 20.10... and recently reinstalled `snapd` and `snap-store`.

`snapd` seems to have reinstalled correctly but `snap-store` stuck on:

> Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "snap-store".

The Ubuntu Software is shown on the apps list but it doesn't start. I think the `(Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "snap-store")` must finish, to start the `snap-store`.

**Terminal Log:**

```
bardia@bardia-Rajabi-Ubuntu:~$ sudo snap install snap-store
[sudo] password for bardia: **********
Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "snap-store"
```

How does one fix this, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me, Snap-store installed successfully after taking some time on "Automatically connect eligible plugs and slots of snap "snap-store". Time depends on your internet speed.

Comment: Agreed; my internet was slow at the moment that I experienced this issue. This points to yet another design flaw with snaps: all dependencies are not being downloaded before installation proceeds. Secondly, the message should have shown some download progress / ETA, or atleast an indication that downloads are happening.